# Transform array into object with custom properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, reduce

I have this array

```
myarr = [
  '=title1',
  'longText0...',
  'longtText1...',
  '=title2',
  'longTextA...',
  'longtTextB...',
  'longtTextC...'     
];
```

symbol `=` indicates that is is a property, next to that is a list of items that belongs to that property

I want to transform that array into object

```
myObj = {
   title1: [
     'longText0...',
     'longtText1...',   
   ],

   title2: [
     'longTextA...',
     'longtTextB...',  
     'longtTextC...'
   ]
}
```

I come up with this code so far:

```
const arrayToObject = (array) =>
   array.reduce((obj, item) => {
     if(item.startsWith('=')) {
       const itemName = item.replace('=', '')
       obj[itemName] = itemName;
     } else {
       
       //add the rest....
     }
 

     return obj
   }, {})


console.log(arrayToObject(myarr))
```

My challenges so far is that I am not sure how to turn `obj[itemName]` so I can assign the items to it. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach which does not depend on outer scope references for keeping track of the currently to be built/aggregated property makes this information part of the reducer function's first parameter, [the `previousValue` which serves as an accumulator/collector object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#grouping_objects_by_a_property).

Thus, as for the OP's task, this collector would feature two properties, the `currentKey` and the `result`, where the former holds the state of the currently processed property name and the latter being the programmatically built result.

```js
// - reducer function which aggregates entries at time,
//   either by creating a new property or by pushing a
//   value into the currently processed property value.
// - keeps the state of the currently processed property
//   by the accumulator`s/collector's `currentKey` property
//   whereas the result programmatically gets build as
//   the accumulator`s/collector's `result` property.

function aggregateEntry({ currentKey = null, result = {} }, item) {
  const key = (item.startsWith('=') && item.slice(1));
  if (
    (key !== false) &&
    (key !== currentKey)
  ) {
    // keep track of the currently processed property name.
    currentKey = key;

    // create a new entry (key value pair).
    result[currentKey] = [];
  } else {
    // push value into the currently processed property value.
    result[currentKey].push(item);
  }
  return { currentKey, result };
}
console.log([
  '=title1',
  'longText0...',
  'longtText1...',
  '=title2',
  'longTextA...',
  'longtTextB...',
  'longtTextC...',
].reduce(aggregateEntry, { result: {} }).result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do that with `reduce` but with a simple `for` loop, because you have to carry the `itemname` over multiple iterations

```
let o = {}, n = ''; 
for (let k of arr) {
  if (k.startsWith('=')) { 
    n = k.substring(1);
    o[n] = []
  } else {
    o[n].push(k);
  }
}
```

You can of course also do it with `reduce`, but you have to put the declaration of `itemname` outside of the callback

```
let n = '';
let o = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (c.startsWith('=')) {
    n = c.substring(1);
    a[n] = [];
  } else {
    a[n].push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, {});
```

Please be aware, there is no error handling, ie the code assumes your array is well structured and the first element in the array must start with `=`

Comment: In terms of code reuse, a **properly named reducer function statement** might even be the favored solution; one just needs to implement the reducer in a way that it keeps track of the currently processed property name.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Yes, might be. But at the level of this question, I assumed code reuse is not the major issue here so I just tried to provide a simple and understandable example of how this can be done ...

Answer (score 0):

The following function will give you the desired results

```
    function arrayToObject(arr)
{
    let returnObj={};
    for(let i =0; i <arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].startsWith('='))
       {
           let itemName = arr[i].replace('=','');
           returnObj[itemName]=[];
           for(let j=i+1; j <arr.length;j++)
           {
               if(arr[j].startsWith('='))
               {
                   break;
               }
               else
                {
                    let value = arr[j];
                    returnObj[itemName].push(value) ;
                }
               
           }
           
       }
    }
    
    return returnObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a version with `reduce`

```js
const myarr = [
  '=title1',
  'longText0...',
  'longtText1...',
  '=title2',
  'longTextA...',
  'longtTextB...',
  'longtTextC...'     
];


const obj = myarr.reduce((res, el) => {
 if(el.startsWith('=')){
   const key = el.substring(1)
   return {
     data: {
       ...res.data,
       [key]: [],
     },
     key
   }
 }
 return {
  ...res,
   data:{
     ...res.data,
     [res.key]: [...res.data[res.key], el]
   }
 }

}, {
 data: {},
 key: ''
}).data

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep the key somewhere separate for a reduce method:

```js
const myarr = ['=title1', 'longText0...', 'longtText1...', '=title2', 'longTextA...', 'longtTextB...', 'longtTextC...'];

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  myarr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if(item.startsWith('='))
      acc.push([item.substring(1), []]);
    else
      acc[acc.length - 1]?.[1].push(item);
    
    return acc;
  }, [])
);

console.log(JSON.stringify( res ));
```